# oracle apex not work the Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connectio

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, apex

[[image]
I install orcle database and oracle apex locally but
I am getting this error, when try to open the workspace

[image]

also the same schema when try to connect through the sql developer not connect and error show
How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the database, you make a request to a "listener" which then hands off your connection to the database.  The listener listens (hence the name) on a port. If your listener is not running, or you are sending your request on the wrong port, then you see errors like this, because we can't find the listener.

Try this on a command line:

lsnrctl status

If you get errors, then your listener probably is not running. Go into Services, and you look for OracleTNS.... and start that. If your output suggests the listener is up and running already, then look for the information about the port and IP address (or hostname) that it is listening on.  You then use those for your connection details in SQLDev and ORDS and the like.

Comment: I check the status of listener in CMD and show that listener not work as in img (new attachment in question)
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
how can I solve that ?

Comment: host 0.0.0.0 does not look right, it should be your machine name, or perhaps localhost. Go into the network/admin folder under 'homes' folder and check listener.ora

Comment: still the same error (update the img)
I edit listener.ora but got the same error
can I reinstall the llistener ? or how to fix that

Comment: fire up "Network Config Assistant" to do that